# Burninate the "tourist" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've just noticed that a [tourist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tourist) tag has snuck in. It's on five questions.

Well apart from the fact it should be 'tourists' or 'tourism' it's probably far too broad to be of any use.

In the question I first spotted it in my guess is that somebody typed "tourist visas" into the tag area. Since tags can't contain spaces and both "tourist" and "visas" already existed as tags, the system happily added them.

I'd be surprised if less than half the questions here are about tourism. Probably most of the questions not about business travel.

In any case for the two more specific fields that come to mind we already have better specific tags: [sightseeing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sightseeing) and [tourist-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tourist-visas).

What think ye?

Comment: @pnuts: Yes if that doesn't go away within a week as part of the system's self-cleaning mechanism, we need to report it as a bug. That way not only will our problem get cleaned up, but similar problems won't be able to affect other SE sites perhaps without being noticed.

Comment: @pnuts: Hmm OK you seem to be quite well versed in the situation (-:

Comment: Maybe there should be more specific tags, such as "businesstravel" or "longtermtravel"? My first question here was not a tourist question but an "expat-questions".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Burn it with fire. It's prone to misuse, has very little value, and as you've noted, better specific tags are available.

Comment: Exactly this. No point in having that tag.

Comment: OK seems unanimous. Let me fill my napalm pack ... Oh somebody beat me to it, they're all black, crispy, and smoking already. (-:

Comment: The only possible use I can think of is for "being a tourist"/"how to conduct oneself" questions like ["Is there a way to prevent “looking like a tourist” in order to not be harassed?"](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59128/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-looking-like-a-tourist-in-order-to-not-be-harassed/59137#59137), but I think [tips-and-tricks](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) covers those sorts of questions better (especially as these questions tend to be "how *not* to be a dumb tourist" `:-)`).